# PHP - db field echoed out in custom attribute is being splitted

Tags: php, attributes

In my db I a have table called users. In that table I have a field called usr_loc_id. The content of that field is a city name with its zip code. An example would be : Paris (75018)

In a php script I am at some point echoing out that field value into a custom attribute of a tr tag :

```
echo '<tr attrLoc='.$row['usr_loc_id'].' class='someClass'>...
```

My problem is as follows. When i check my debugger, I see that only the city name is take into consideration. The city code with the parenthises is left out. Here below how it looks in the debugger.

```
<tr attrLoc="Paris" (75018) class="someClass">...
```

Hope someone can help understand and solve this. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

Comment: Where is `"` double quotes coming from? Is that coming from db? Or you say that `Paris` is encloded in double quotes but not zip code ?

Comment: The last code line is what is being displayed in my Chrome debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing quotes in the generated html. The literal text of your output is:

```
<tr attrLoc=Paris (75018) class=someClass>...
```

Note that lack of quotes. That means the browser's parser is seeing *3* attributes in this tag:

1. attrLoc = Paris
2. invalid attribute (75018)
3. classs = someClass

With proper quoting in your PHP, you can fix this:

```
echo <<<EOL
<tr attrLoc="{$row['usr_loc_id']}" class="someClass"> ...
EOL;
```

or

```
echo '<tr attrLoc="' . $row['usr_loc_id'] . '" class="someClass"> ...';
                  ^--missing                 ^--missing
```

Comment: Hello Marc. You are totally right. Forgot the double quotations mark everywhre. It made the trick. Rooky mistake! I am a rooky so it should be Ok... You have an awesome first name by the way :)

Comment: +1 that's what I suspected initially but wasn't sure because he could not explain it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the quoted code you will want to add some quotations. Since the city name is the only content contained within the quotes, that's all that will be displayed. I will show you another method using double quotes and curly brace:

```
echo "<tr attrLoc='{$row['user_loc_id']}' class='someClass'>";
```

Does this solve it?

Comment: does your DB entry for that city contain any quotes? In your output, it shows "Paris" (75018), but in your echo statement you have no quotes used. If those quotes are coming from your databse you might want to clense them with addslashes (`echo "<tr attrLoc='{addslashes($row['user_loc_id'])}' class='someClass'>";`)

Comment: No my filed does not contain any quotes. The format is like that: Paris (75018)

Comment: Adding slashed did not made the trick unfortunately echo '<tr attrLoc='.addslashes($row['usr_loc_id']).' class='someClass'>...

Comment: Ben, thanks for trying to help. Problem solved. Check Marc B input... Thanks again for taking time anyway.